# Access list of values from a function in another function in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a function that gathers a list of UPCs. I created another function to take the list and search for prices. The issue I am having is when a UPC is not found, a KeyError occurs. How do ignore the UPCs with no match and continue with the code? The current version of the code is an infinite loop.

```
def trending():
    trending = requests.get('http://api.com/trends?format=json&apiKey={}'.format(apiKey))
    trendingResponse = trending.json()
    items = trendingResponse['items']

    for item in items:
        price = item['salePrice']
        name = item['name']
        upc = item['upc']
        stock = item['stock']
        image = item['largeImage']
        url = item['productUrl']
        sDescription = item['shortDescription']
        brandName = item['brandName']
        availableOnline = item['availableOnline']

        print('Current UPC = ' + str(upc))
        return upc_lookup(upc)

def upc_lookup(upc):
    products_api = mws.Products(access_key, secret_key, seller_id, region='US')
    # lookup product by upc
    products = products_api.get_matching_product_for_id(marketplaceid=marketplace_usa, type_='UPC', ids=upc)
    parse = products.parsed

    while True:
        try:
            # return asin from UPC lookup
            asin = parse['Products']['Product']['Identifiers']['MarketplaceASIN']['ASIN']['value']
            print('ASIN Found = ' + str(asin))
        except KeyError:
            print('UPC {} not Found in Amazon'.format(upc))
```

Comment: What line gives you error? Post a complete error message.

Comment: The current code doesn't have an error, it's an infinite loop. The error happens at             asin = parse['Products']['Product']['Identifiers']['MarketplaceASIN']['ASIN']['value']
 the values I am trying to parse aren't there when a UPC isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to move my Return in the first function out of the For Loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_1():
    function_1.item = {'sale-Price':100, 'name':'ABC', 'stock':3, 'brand-name':4}`

def function_2():
    item = function_1.item
    sp = item['salePrice']
    name = item['name']
    stock = item['stock']
    print(sp, name, stock)

function_1()
function_2()
```